# Partial linq text searching with Contains

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm trying to do a text search on a partial property match on related entities.

My entities are:

```
public class TradeContact
{
    [Key]
    public int TradeContactId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Region> Regions { get; set; }

}

public class Region
{
    [Key]
    public int RegionId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TradeContact> TradeContacts { get; set; }
}
```

My goal is that if a TradeContact has the following regions: Sydney, Brisbane, Darwin, then I should be able to search for 'Syd' to retrieve that TradeContact record.

Currently I'm searching like this:

```
TradeContacts = TradeContacts
    .Where(s => s.Regions.Select(x => x.Name.ToUpper())
    .Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
```

This code finds full matches, so 'Sydney' will return my TradeContact, but it doesn't work on partial matches.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: @wudzik This is not a duplicate of that question. OP already knows how to perform a comparison, they are asking how to perform the comparison on a list of strings using LINQ. More precisely, they are asking what is wrong with the current solution they have in that it isn't matching on partial matches.

Comment: Well until this question gets unflagged, here is your working code, and apologies that I can't format it better as a comment: `TradeContacts = TradeContacts.Where(s => s.Regions.Any(r => r.Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())));`

Comment: @wudzik this question is not related to the question you marked as duplicate in _any_ way at all.

Comment: @Evk sorry, my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to understand *why* current approach does not work.

```
TradeContacts
.Where(s => s.Regions.Select(x => x.Name.ToUpper())
.Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
```

If translate that to human language, it would be: give me Contacts where the *list* of Regions *contains* region with the Name *equal* to searchString. So Contains you use is not `String.Contains`, it's `IEnumerable.Contains`:

```
var regionNames = new List<string>();
var match = regionNames.Contains(searchString);
```

As you see, that indeed matches only when region name *equals* your search string.

```
TradeContacts.Where(s => s.Regions.
   Any(x => x.Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
```

This one is different: give me all Contacts where any region has *Name* which *contains* searchString.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

```
var result = TradeContacts.Where(s => s.Regions.
             Any(x => x.Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));

if(result!=null)
//do your stuff.
```

Comment: This only returns the first result found as opposed to all matching entities.

Comment: You can use where in this case

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here's the answer that I posted before:

```
TradeContacts = TradeContacts.Where(
            s => s.Regions.Any(
                r => r.Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())));
```

The reason your current code isn't working is because you are performing the `Contains` check on your list of names, which checks the list for exact matches, when what you want to be doing is checking the names themselves.